# How to prevent default language to be forced when using string format

Tags: android, string, textview, locale, number-formatting

So I Have a TextView in my calculator app that I eventually display the results in it ...
It works ... but recently during the testing I found out that if The Default Language of That device is set to a non-english language (for example arabic or farsi) numbers in TextView get to be shown in that specific language (not english) and in a completely different format !!
  I used this code to generate the result

`result = String.format("%.4f", mResultBeforeFormatting);
 resultTextView.settext(result);`

also to note is that if I set the TextView with a hard coded string the issue doesn't happen

```
resultTextView.settext("343");
```

[image: Here Default Language is set to persian but I want my text (25) to be shown in english regardless of Default Language]

[image: Correct Form]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formats used by the `String.format` method will by default be the formats specified by the device's default locale.

If you want to force the use of a specific locale, use the [`String.format` method that accepts a locale parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)).

For example:

```
result = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%.4f", mResultBeforeFormatting);
```

Comment: The problem is also with the locale of the TextView. In API level 17 or after, it is possible to individually set locale of the TextView: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextLocale(java.util.Locale)